# Var with {} break IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, slidetoggle

Im having an issue using slideToggle as a variable on my website. Im using domSlider. When I try the following I get issues I cannot understand.

If define slideToggle as:

```
var {slideToggle} = window.domSlider;
```

I get `SCRIPT1010: Expected identifier` in IE 11. But works in Chrome and modern browsers.

And if I define it as:

```
var slideToggle = window.domSlider;
```

I get `Uncaught TypeError: slideToggle is not a function` In chrome and other modern browsers. But no errors in IE 11.

I dont know what is causing this, and how to move on from here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IE11 doesn't support destructuring assignment: [Browser_compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Browser_compatibility)

```
var { slideToggle } = window.domSlider;
```

would be:

```
var slideToggle = window.domSlider.slideToggle;
```

to work in IE11, or you can just use `window.domSlider.slideToggle` directly

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I mark it as answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

The `var { item } = func()` construct is called *destructuring*. The older Redmond Middle School Science Project (IE11) doesn't support it; it's from a javascript version that came after they stopped working on IE.

If you're targeting IE, scroll to the bottom of the MDN page describing the feature. For your example, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#  It says which browsers support the feature.

There's also a site called [CanIUse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=destructuring) with information, feature by feature, about browser support.

There's a transpiler (a compiler that turns new javascript into old) called [Babel](https://babeljs.io/). You could try that. But explaining how to rig it in your project is too much for a SO answer.

Welcome to the wonderful world of developing code for bad legacy browsers. There's a good reason for Microsoft abandoning their own browser development and adopting Chromium.